# Setting up DNS for e-mail serving

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, email-server, bind

I have a CentOS6 Server and wanted to install Zimbra 7. I was getting an /etc/hosts error and found out that I need to run a local DNS Server due to split-dns issues.

I installed Bind and am trying to configure it.

In: `/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf`

```
options {
    directory "/var/named";
    dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8 ;
        8.8.4.4 ;
    };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";
// Specify that this server is the master for mail.domain.com
zone "mail.thedigiologygroup.org" {
    type master;
    file "db.mail.thedigiologygroup.org";
};
```

I dont know is using Google Public DNS is right here.

In: `/var/named/chroot/var/named/db.mail.thedigiologygroup.org`

```
@   IN  SOA     @ root (
                           10118      ; Serial
                           43200      ; Refresh
                           3600   ; Retry
                           3600000    ; Expire
                           2592000 )  ; Minimum

           IN      NS      @
           IN      A       75.149.56.27
           IN      MX      10 mail.thedigiologygroup.org.
```

Bind start correctly I switch the DNS servers on the NIC to 127.0.0.1 and try to install Zimbra again and I get the same error that started this process of:

`ERROR: Installation can not proceeed.  Please fix your /etc/hosts file
  to contain:

Where  is the ip address of the host, 
   is the FULLY QUALIFIED host name, and
   is the (optional) hostname-only portion`

my `/etc/hosts` is right with:

`127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4`

`::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`

`192.168.1.27 thedigiologyroup.org`

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the installation requires including the FQDN in the `/etc/hosts` file. You can get your FQDN using:

```
$ hostname -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to confuse host names and domain names, they're different by subtly so.

In your named.conf file, you specify the domain name as mail.xxx.org- which means the 'mail' subdomain of xxx.org, which is likely not what you want (there would be hosts a.mail.xxx.org and b.mail.xxx.org in that domain).  You probably should put xxx.org there to define this as the DNS record for the xxx.org domain.

And in your hosts file, you put xxx.org, which is your domain name.  You should put the actual hostname which is 'mail.xxx.org'.  The /etc/hosts line you want is:
192.168.1.27  mail.digiologygroup.org mail

Also, you have defined mail as the MX server in the db.xxx file, but you do not have
an A record that defines the address for it.  So there should be a line like:
mail  IN  A  192.168.1.27

Good luck!